# Chrome Plugin text forwarding

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm working on a Chrome plugin and I need help with forwarding the data from popup.html to background.js

I would like to paste the text into the input textbox in popup and be able to use it in background script, currently, it should only append the text, but I plan to use text manipulation to automate a "database" input work.
From excel via my plugin to certain forms.

*Manifest.json*

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

      "name": "LMT",
      "description": "This extension will save your life",
      "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
       "default_icon": "icon.png",
       "default_popup": "popup.html",
       "default_title": "LMT"
  },
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]

  },
    "content_scripts":[{
        "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
        "js":["contentscript.js"]

}],
      "permissions": [
       "activeTab",
       "background" ,
       "tabs",
       "http://*/*",
       "https://*/*"
   ]
}
```

*Popup.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="contentscript.js"></script>
    <style>body{height: 100px;width: 200px;}</style>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Welcome to Upload tool</p>
    <input type="text" id="inputxt">
    <button id="start">Start</button>

</body>
</html>
```

*Content.js*

```
(function() {

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        var element = document.getElementById('start');

        var txtimport = document.getElementById('inputxt');
        element.addEventListener('click', function () {


                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"background.js"});

                //alert("BOF");

        });
    });


})();
```

*background.js*

```
var x = document.createElement("div");
var t = document.createTextNode("This is a paragraph.");
x.appendChild(t);
x.style.width = "80%";
x.style.marginLeft = "50px";
x.style.height = "300px";
x.style.background = "#499";
x.style.color = "white";
document.body.appendChild(x);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to pass data, or just communicate between background.js and Content.js you should look at [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)

This article has some good examples.